# Trying to print out JS variable in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print out the variables val1-5 in HTML. Doesn't seem to be working, any help would be appreciated.

```
var val1 = 0;
var val2 = 0;
var val3 = 0;
var val4 = 0;
var val5 = 0;
var fing = prompt("enter code");

window.onload = function(){
    var str = fing;
    var res = str.charAt()
    val1 = res;

    //str 2//
    var str = fing;
    var res1 = str.charAt(1)
    val2 = res1;
    var str = fing;
    var res2 = str.charAt(2)
    val3 = res2;
};
</script>

<p id="var1"></p>
<p id="var2"></p>
<p id="var3"></p>
```

Comment: OK. Let's go to the beginning. What exactly are you trying to do? Why are val4 and val5 defined and not used? How do you envision this page working?

Comment: At what point are you trying to print the variables? Print them to the console?

Comment: `document.getElementById('var1').innerHTML = var1`, and so on.

Comment: Looks like someone cannot be bothered to solve an assignment with any amount of own effort involved.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to be working" is not very helpful. What is happening that shouldn't, was isn't happening that should? What is the error console telling you? You have not included any code that "prints" the values in any way. A [MCVE] is always a good idea.

Comment: Here is a link to a helpful series of tutorials that will introduce you to javascript. https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i am clueless about your end game and for some reason your code doesn't make sense but..

to print in HTML, You need to do something like..

```
document.getElementById("var1").innerHTML = val1
```

Comment: Thanks for a) solving the question and b) not question my *normal* motives

Comment: Okay cool. Click that tick arrow if this answer solves your purpose (this means that this question is answered)

Answer (score -1):

JS:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = val1
```

HTML:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Your code breaks because of the weird quotes you used.  Use normal quotes when answering questions

Comment: Um weird.... mobile keyboard